# how can i make the thumbnails appear with the dynamic php thumbnail generator?

Tags: php

hello i'm trying to create my own automatic php photo gallery from directory without a database almost similar to that ubergallery script but being that that script doesnt have sub album directories im creating my own.

The first part is to generate the square thumbnails script. i've learn from this tutorial [here](http://betterphp.co.uk/playlist.html?pid=PL812FB62BCB69CCEC) everything was typed word of word and followed the directions correctly

when i preview the page, no thumbnail showed up, the link to the image and the folder creating work but no image thumbnail showed up. i am using dreamweaver to preview my php page and wamp server and also i check the php gd extensions and they all enable. but still no luck showing the thumbnail can someone please help me

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['img'])){
    if (file_exists($_GET['img'])){
        ignore_user_abort(true);
        set_time_limit(120);
        ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');

        $src_size = getimagesize($_GET['img']);

        if ($src_size === false){
            die('That does not look like a image.');
        }

        $thumb_width  = 250;
        $thumb_height = 200;

        if ($src_size['mine'] === 'image/jpeg'){
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['img']);
        }else if ($src_size['mine'] === 'image/png'){
            $src = imagecreatefrompng($_GET['img']);
        }else if ($src_size['mine'] === 'image/gif'){
            $src = imagecreatefromgif($_GET['img']);
        }

        $src_aspect = round(($src_size[0] / $src_size[1]), 1);
        $thumb_aspect = round(($thumb_width / $thumb_height), 1);

        if ($src_aspect < $thumb_aspect){
            // higher
            $new_size = array($thumb_width, ($thumb_width / $src_size[0]) * $src_size[1]);
            $src_pos = array(0, (($new_size[1] - $thumb_height) * ($src_size[1] / $new_size[1])) / 2);
        }else if ($src_aspect > $thumb_aspect){
            //wider
            $new_size = array(($thumb_width / $src_size[1]) * $src_size[0], $thumb_height);
            $src_pos = array((($new_size[0] - $thumb_width) * ($src_size[0] / $new_size[0])) / 2, 0);
        }else{
            // same shape
            $new_size = array($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
            $src_pos = array(0, 0);
        }

        if ($new_size[0] < 1) $new_size[0] = 1;
        if ($new_size[1] < 1) $new_size[1] = 1;

        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
        imagecopyresampled($thumb, $src, 0, 0, $src_pos[0], $src_pos[1], $new_size[0], $new_size[1], $src_size[0], $src_size[1]);

        if ($src_size['mine'] === 'image/jpeg'){
            imagejpeg($thumb, "thumbs/{$_GET['img']}");
        }else if ($src_size['mine'] === 'image/png'){
            imagepng($thumb, "thumbs/{$_GET['img']}");
        }else if ($src_size['mine'] === 'image/gif'){
            imagegif($thumb, "thumbs/{$_GET['img']}");
        }

        header("Location: thumbs/{$_GET['img']}");
    }

    die();
}

if (is_dir('./thumbs') === false){
    mkdir('./thumbs', 0744);
}

$images = glob('*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php

    foreach ($images as $image){
        if (file_exists("./thumbs/{$image}")){
            echo "<a href=\"{$image}\"><img src=\"thumbs/{$image}\" alt\"{$image}\" /></a>";
        }else{
            echo "<a href=\"{$image}\"><img src=\"?img={$image}\" alt\"{$image}\" /></a>";
        }
    }

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Personal observation: I don't like video tutorials when its about programming.

Comment: More on topic: The thumbnails should be located at `thumbs/<name of image>`. Are they? I don't see you generating them. The PHP code at the beginning is probably never used.

Comment: everything was follow to the T when i did this code and it worked on his screen but it didnt worked on mines, only the link to the original image work when click but no thumbnail image show up, i even tried other thumbnail generators and still the same results

Comment: Try to understand your own code: Yes, there is code to generate thumbnails, but it is never used.